# Does it make sense to compute adjusted $r^2$ with test set?

Tags: time-series, matlab, r-squared, regression-coefficients

I have divided my time series into training and testing set. I would like to know if makes sense to compute the adjusted $r^2$ with the testing set or just on the training stage.

Comment: how are you adjusting $R^2$ (what is it being adjusted by/for)? Is it already being adjusted for number or predictors, for example? If you're applying it to the test set, why would it need to be adjusted?

Comment: @Glen_b Does that even make sense to compare adjusted R2 in the training and testing set? To me, this metric is only used to prevent overfitting and create a model. Once we've got the model, we simply evaluate the accuracy with the test data.

Comment: @StudentT I think we're both trying to make the same point, but perhaps I was doing it less clearly.

Comment: @Glen_b, I have adjusted it to the number of predictors.

Comment: @StudentT, I do not want to compare the adjusted R2 in the training and the testing set. I want to compare in the testing set but with different models. For example, I test a linear model and a svr model and I want to compare them or even within each model compare the number of predictors. I already have the RMSE but from what I read I thought  that I could use adjusted R2 to check the best number of predictors. So, what does make sense for you to compare different models that have a certain range of number of predictors?

Comment: Why would that matter when assessing on the test set?

Comment: @Glen_b and lns I hear you. But why would you want to do it? Usually, we only assess the best model (from training) with the test set. The idea is to assess what would happen if we get a new set of data that we have never seen. Bt here, you're trying to fit those new data. This doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to train a model with part of the dataset and then check how good it is with the testing set. Then I compare some performance metrics like the RMSE and I can choose the best one (regarding the RMSE obtained with the test set). The test set is important as it is new data that the model haven't seen yet ... it is really for testing the model.

Answer (score 3):

The $R^2_{adj}$ on the training set should more closely approximate the $R^2$ of the test set. $R^2_{adj}$ is to try to prevent you from over-fitting on the training data.

Have you tried comparing the $R^2$ and $R^2_{adj}$ of the training set to the $R^2$ of the test set for different sample sets?

$R^2_{adj}$ still has value on the test set if you plan to use model on more data in the future. It will be a more reliable estimate of $R^2$ on future datasets.

Comment: I haven't tried that but I almost certain that the values will be different. I calculated the adjusted R^2 since I saw that it is better to compare models with different number of predictors.

Comment: You can take different test and train samples of the data to test my suggestion.

Comment: I know that I can .. my question is if it makes sense to compute the adjusted r^2 on the testing set and also how can I interpret the result.